# Can't Send Email with Java/Play Mailer

Tags: java, email, playframework

I am trying to send an email via the Play Framework `Mailer` class, but I keep getting the same ClassCastException. Here's the console output:

```
-- Exception in thread "DataHandler.getInputStream" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to java.lang.String
-- at org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.TextHandler.writeTo(TextHandler.java:143)
-- at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
-- at javax.activation.DataHandler$1.run(DataHandler.java:266)
-- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
-- 16:48:06,606 ERROR ~
--
-- @79gebib82
-- The email has not been sent
--
-- Mail error
-- A mail error occurred : Error while sending email
--
-- play.exceptions.MailException: Error while sending email
-- at play.libs.Mail$1.call(Mail.java:193)
-- at play.libs.Mail$1.call(Mail.java:184)
-- at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
-- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
-- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
-- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
-- Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.mailgun.org:465
-- at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
-- at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
-- at play.libs.Mail$1.call(Mail.java:190)
-- ... 5 more
-- Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Converting body of type text/html; charset=UTF-8 failed)
-- at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
-- at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
-- at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
-- ... 7 more
-- Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Converting body of type text/html; charset=UTF-8 failed
-- at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.convertAttachmentToString(GMTransport.java:368)
-- at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:217)
-- at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
-- ... 9 more
```

And here is the code that Im using to send the email:

```
SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setFrom("noreply@draftr.app");
email.addTo("signup@draftr.app");
email.setSubject("New Pending User");
email.setMsg("Hey this is a test");
Mail.send(email);
```

I'm using Mailgun to send my emails, and this doesn't appear to be an issue with that configuration. I came across this error after branching off an existing, functional, application that is live and sending emails correctly.

For this reason, the ClassCastException doesn't make a lot of sense since Im using the same architecture and html form styles as the existing application. What gives?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see a `ClassCastException` in the above. I see an failure on the `convertAttachmentToString(...)`. Is there some other information that suggests the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: @KevinO My apologies. I updated the log output. Should be there now

Comment: SimpleEmail and Mail are your classes? Could you put the code ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski Nope. `SimpleMail` is from `apache.commons.mail` and `Mail` is a PlayFramework class

Comment: Could you put the dependency to PlayFramework ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/home

Answer (score 0):

Update your mail jar to 1.5.x version. this error has been resolved in that version